# Alternatives to 'In The Pink'?

Tags: phrases

I'm looking for alternatives to 'in the pink'.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. For us to help you, you should [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/234681/edit) your question to indicate which meaning of *in the pink* you mean, why you want to avoid it, and what efforts you have made (e.g. web searches, thesauruses) to find alternatives, and what alternative suggestions are unsuitable and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not often I hear people say "in the pink" these days. If we are trying to say that we are feeling good, especially from the point of view of health we might say we are:

- Feeling chipper
- In Tip-top shape
- Cooking with gas
- Firing on all cylinders
- Ready to Rock
- Good to go

Comment: Thanks. This helped me :) But, do you have more such phrase suggestions?

Comment: They are the ones that immediately came to mind, but the list will be endless. "Bright-eyed and Bushy Tailed", "Rocking and Rolling", "Locked and Loaded" ...